# Is it safe to install outdated intel Linux Graphics Installer for 14.04.4?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, intel-graphics

I have ubuntu 14.04.4 and intel hd 4000. Recent releases of Linux Graphics Installer only support 15.10+ versions, but after little but of googling I found a working link to an [outdated version](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7) that supports 14.04.4 (I guess?) [[deb]](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/14.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-linux-graphics-installer/intel-linux-graphics-installer_1.0.7-0intel1_amd64.deb)

I wonder if it's safe to try to install it. The reason I bother about it is because with recent chrome release, playing 1080p-60fps youtube videos without hardware acceleration became a real struggle (even with extention that enforces use of h264.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't hesitate to try it, if I were in your place.  There is no part of the Linux system that depends on prioritized drivers for one video card over another.  In the best case, you see an improvement.  At worst, things perform more poorly and you can simply uninstall.

Good luck to you.